# How to connect a small conveyor to a normal one?

Tags: space-engineers

I'm building a small Ship and i want to add a connector to a medium cargo container. Both normal sized sides are in use. Because of this I only have the small opening facing the right direction.

Is there a way to connect a small opening to a big one without an additional cargo container?

[image: My problem.]

**Edit**

And i know, i could use the small opening on the connector, but i would prefer it this way.

**Edit2**

I finally used a conveyor block, but i would still like to know, how to map these two openings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, big conveyor doors must be connected to other big conveyor doors. Same goes for the small ones.

Best thing you can do in that picture above is to rotate the cargo container 90 degrees to the left or to the right, so that the big opening is facing towards the connector. Then place a big conveyor with it's small doors to the top and bottom so the big doors are connected to the connector and cargo container, while at the same time the other 2 remaining big doors are on it's sides. Then remove the conveyor tubes you've placed now and place them on the conveyor cube's sides, then reconnect the blocks you had connected with the tubes before moving them.

Also tip: Small conveyor doors CAN'T move components (steel grids, large steel tubes, etc), they only allow access for Oxygen, equipment (tools, guns, ammo) and ores/ingots (small amounts at a time). Large conveyor doors can move every component and can move ores/ingots at a larger amount at a time.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can connect them, build a connector on one side of a large conveyor then on a small connector build a medium cargo and on that second connector, then connect them together and it will be okay. But connector are a little bit problematic because of a bug in older versions, it works now but if you have an old save it may cause problems.